# how to bring to front DIV

Tags: css, html

Hi I'm having a problem regarding bringing `DIV` to front to other `DIV`.

here my sample code:**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9b9QL/)**

In my sample in JSFIDDLE I have a menu bar and a sub menu, my problem is when the sub menu shows it on the back of other **DIV**

**Thank you in ADVANCE!**

Comment: Where do you want to show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `z-index` to your `ul` and you are done:

```
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul { z-index: 10;}
```

Comment: Thanks! There a weird thing happened, in JSFIDDLE your answer is actually working but when i put it on my project it doesn't work.. how could that happen??

Comment: try giving less z-index to your `#slides` like `#slides { z-index:1;}` if doesn't work then we would need your original code.

Comment: yes i already did that. but no luck. 

actually thats the original code. or do you want the `CSS` file I use?

Comment: dont know why but the problem is `#cssmenu > ul { opacity: 0.7}`. I removed and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `z-index` css property to arrange the z-dimension of your divs. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have given the property-

```
display: none;
```

to your `<li>`, that;s why the first div is empty

Answer (score 1):

add     `z-index: 99;` in your following class

```
 #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul
```

Comment: I don't have any `display: none;` in my `#cssmenu > ul li` but it's `#cssmenu > ul li {display: inline-block;*display: inline;zoom: 1;}`

Comment: are you  testing it in the jsfiddle??

Comment: ok please drag your your output section to the left then view it  is working there